# Can’t access my files

Tags: windows, user-accounts, user-profiles, user

I cannot access my main user in Windows , so I can’t access my files or applications .
I’ve linked a video describing the problem .

https://photos.app.goo.gl/St9Df3LuKWUmQFc57

Well, basically it is telling me that windows cannot connect to my Microsoft account even though I enter my correct password. And I connect to the account through the settings and nothing changes, I still work with a temporary profile created by windows .
In the other hand I have another admin user , but the most of my stuff isn’t shared with that user .
Hope my case is clear otherwise tell me in comments:)

So I need a way to access my main user again.
And thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept videos of issues. Describe your problem **in the question**.

Comment: Have you tried a "forgot my password" or whatever Windows' account recovery feature is?

Comment: Yes tried it :(